# Extract a single value from ONTAP output

Tags: ansible, ontap

How can I extract the version from the lengthy output of the module `netapp.ontap.na_ontap_rest_info`?

This is my playbook and its output is quite lengthy

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  collections:
    - netapp.ontap
  tasks:
  - name: run ONTAP gather facts for cluster_node_info
    netapp.ontap.na_ontap_rest_info:
      hostname: "{{ lookup('env', 'ClusterName') }}"
      username: "{{ lookup('env', 'ontap_admin_usr') }}"
      password: "{{ lookup('env', 'ontap_admin_pwd') }}"
      use_rest: always
      https: true
      validate_certs: false
      gather_subset:
        - cluster_node_info
      fields:
        - 'version'
```

From the example output below, I only need the first part of the version full, namely `NetApp Release 9.12.1P4`

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "cert_filepath": null,
            "feature_flags": null,
            "fields": [
                "version"
            ],
            "force_ontap_version": null,
            "gather_subset": [
                "cluster_node_info"
            ],
            "hostname": "clusterhostname",
            "http_port": null,
            "https": true,
            "ignore_api_errors": null,
            "key_filepath": null,
            "max_records": 1024,
            "ontapi": null,
            "owning_resource": null,
            "parameters": null,
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "state": null,
            "use_python_keys": false,
            "use_rest": "always",
            "username": "svc_ans-ontap",
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    },
    "ontap_info": {
        "cluster/nodes": {
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "/api/cluster/nodes?max_records=1024&fields=version"
                }
            },
            "num_records": 2,
            "records": [
                {
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/cluster/nodes/578658e0-87fc-11e9-b8bd-00a098f2ea00"
                        }
                    },
                    "name": "node2",
                    "uuid": "578658e0-87fc-11e9-b8bd-00a098f2ea00",
                    "version": {
                        "full": "NetApp Release 9.12.1P4: Tue Jun 06 20:41:34 UTC 2023",
                        "generation": 9,
                        "major": 12,
                        "minor": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "/api/cluster/nodes/6aae0abe-a410-11e9-ae1d-00a098f2ea72"
                        }
                    },
                    "name": "node1",
                    "uuid": "6aae0abe-a410-11e9-ae1d-00a098f2ea72",
                    "version": {
                        "full": "NetApp Release 9.12.1P4: Tue Jun 06 20:41:34 UTC 2023",
                        "generation": 9,
                        "major": 12,
                        "minor": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to add to the playbook to process the version output to return only `NetApp Release 9.12.1P4`?

Answer (score 1):

You should, first, [*register*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) the output of your task.

Then, you can access the different keys with [either the dot or array notations](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#ansible-allows-dot-notation-and-array-notation-for-variables-which-notation-should-i-use), and since you do have a slash in the key `cluster/nodes`, you will at least have to use the array notation there.

Since you do have a list in `records`, you might want to use the [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) filter in order to get version for all the items of that list.

Then you can further use the `map` filter to split the string and extract the part you're interested in.

So, in the end your tasks should be:

```yaml
- name: run ONTAP gather facts for cluster_node_info
  netapp.ontap.na_ontap_rest_info:
    hostname: "{{ lookup('env', 'ClusterName') }}"
    username: "{{ lookup('env', 'ontap_admin_usr') }}"
    password: "{{ lookup('env', 'ontap_admin_pwd') }}"
    use_rest: always
    https: true
    validate_certs: false
    gather_subset:
      - cluster_node_info
    fields:
      - 'version'
  register: cluster_node_info

- debug:
    var: >- 
      cluster_node_info.ontap_info['cluster/nodes'].records
        | map(attribute='version.full')
        | map('split', ':')
        | map(attribute=0)
```

Which would yield

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  ? |-
    cluster_node_info.ontap_info['cluster/nodes'].records
      | map(attribute='version.full')
      | map('split', ':')
      | map(attribute=0)
  : - NetApp Release 9.12.1P4
    - NetApp Release 9.12.1P4
```

Comment: Thank you,  
  
when I run the new playbook, the debug task did not return the values:  
ansible-playbook NetApp_version.yml -vvv<br/>
  
TASK [debug]  
task path: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Infra-NetApp_ONTAP_Upgrade/NetApp_version.yml:21  
ok: [localhost] => {  
    "cluster_node_info.ontap_info['cluster/nodes'].records\n  | map(attribute='version.full')\n  | map('split', ':')\n  | map(attribute=0)": "<generator object do_map at 0x7f9cc64584c0>"  
}  
META: ran handlers  
META: ran handlers

Comment: You are on a pretty old version of Ansible and you should consider upgrading. But on an old version like this, just throw a `| list` at the end to cast the generator into a list.